# Customize the word "in" in biblatex @incollection entry

Tags: biblatex

Is there a way to change the word "in" that appears in the references of a `@incollection` entry in `biblatex`?

I have this:

> candler, Graham V. Finite-Difference Methods for Continuous-Time Dynamic Programming. **In**: marimon, Ramon;scott, Andrew (Ed.).Computational Methods for the Study of Dynamic Economies. Oxford University Press, 18 out. 2001.P. 172–194

What I want is this:

> candler, Graham V. Finite-Difference Methods for Continuous-Time Dynamic Programming. **Em**: marimon, Ramon;scott, Andrew (Ed.).Computational Methods for the Study of Dynamic Economies. Oxford University Press, 18 out. 2001.P. 172–194.

Answer (score 2):

As mentioned in [Guido](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/16895/guido)'s comment, you could tell BibLaTeX which language you are using.

You can accomplish this via [`babel`](https://ctan.org/pkg/babel):

```
\usepackage[portuguese]{babel}
```

and ensure you load BibLaTeX via:

```
\usepackage[backend=biber,sortlocale=auto]{biblatex}
```

Alternatively, if using, e.g., `english`, you can localize this particular string, which is under the `in` keyword, as described in §3.9 of the [BibLaTeX manual](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/biblatex):

```
\DefineBibliographyStrings{english}{%
    in = {em}
}
```